# Store multiple properties of an item

Tags: json, mongodb

My question is more related of choosing the right pattern than an actual problem. Let's suppose I have a database where I store information about several items. These items have all sorts of properties (width, height, weight etc) but not all items have the same. When I transfer the data from the database to the client application I encode the data to a json string. So far I came up with two different representation of the same data and I wanted to know if one has any advantage over the another, or both of them are fine to use.

```
{
    ...
    properties :
    {
        property1 : "value1",
        property2 : "value2"
    }
}

{
    ...
    properties : 
    [
        {
            property_name : "property1",
            property_value : "value1"
        },
        {
            property_name : "property2",
            property_value : "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the first representation I'm using an embedded document to store the properties whereas in the second format I'm using an array.

None of the items have two property with the same name but different value, but two item can share the same property.

The first method seems simpler to me but I'm curious if is there a *prefered* way to do this.

Comment: I would go with the first as long as no duplicates will appear - it's smaller and easier to query. Only advantages of the second one is better compression and possibility of duplicated properties.